# In which countries do football club's second teams play in the main league system?

Tags: rules, football, trivia

I know in Spain [Real Madrid Castilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Madrid_Castilla), Real Madrid's second team, play in the same league system as the first team. Are there other countries in which the same situation occurs, and if so which ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rules related to the reserve teams are different in every country.

- Spanish clubs can have reserve teams play as high as in Liga B but only under-23 players, or under-25 players with a professional contract, can switch between senior and reserve teams.
- In Germany and France, reserve teams are not allowed into the second tier of their respective leagues. The set-up in the Bundesliga means there are separate squads for the first and reserve teams and players cannot move between squads during the season. Those squads are typically, but not exclusively, made up of under-23 players.
- In Portugal, Porto, Benfica, Sporting, Braga, Maritimo and Guimaraes all have B teams in the Portuguese second tier. Their squads must contain ten players who have come through the club’s youth academy and they can include three players who are over 23 years of age.
- In Norway, reserve teams from Premier Division clubs can only be promoted as far as the third tier of their league, providing a one division buffer between teams from the same club

[Source](http://www.extratime.ie/newsdesk/articles/11538/rules-vary-for-european-reserve-teams/)

Conversely, in England and in Scotland, reserve teams do not compete in the main league system.

Comment: In Germany it is possible to move betewwn the squads during the season. Lot of first team players play in the second team for gaining match practice after long injurys. Or team managers come back to second team players, if there're a lot of injured players in the first team. e.g. Daniel Ginczek: playing for VfB Stuttgart (first team) normaly, but played in second team two times this season so far.